# Now to create an A Record on Cloud DNS for Custom Domain for GAE app?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-dns

I moved my site to GAE and am using a custom domain. Now  I want to move DNS records from my old hosting company to **Google Cloud DNS**.   I haven't been able to figure out what the IP is for my app so I can create an A Record.  When I look up the sub-domain that resides on appengine I get a "(no DNS answer)" - it is a CNAME record that resides on my current host's name servers (mobile.xxx.com) and points to ghs.googlehosted.com

I used the Zone Manager in the Developer's Console, created a Zone and have had four Google cloud domain servers assigned.

Since I don't have an IP, do I instead associate my base domain with my appspot project from the console menu->Compute->App Engine->Settings->Custom Domain ? (where it looks like I can also add CNAME records?)

.. or should I go to the Zone Manager to to add the CNAME records?

...and once I copy my appspot site's assigned nameservers to my registrar, my entire site will be running on GAE?

thanks!

Comment: So now I have my 4 IP addresses obtained from the Developer's Console Appengine->Settings-Custom Domain.    I went to the menu item Cloud DNS where I created a Zone.  I then created an A record and entered the four IP addresses.  
...OR should I have created FOUR A Records?
Should I assign one of those A Records to DNS www.example.com and another to mobile.example.com   OR should those subdomains be set up as CNAME records?

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple A records as part of your Recordset of the zone you have configured.

In Cloud DNS UI, create your zone, say testexample.com.  Once created Cloud DNS would give you NS and SOA records for your zone.

Now click on "Add RecordSet".
1) Enter the DNS Name as mobile.testexample.com.
2) Select Resource Record Type as "A" record
3) Enter the IPV4 address. You could click on "Add Item" to add all your 4 IP address for mobile.testexample.com.

Save the changes. Once your DNS config is propagated, port 53 queries for your domain should be answered by Google Cloud DNS

Comment: Thanks - I have everything up and running.  I'm still unsure what's happening where...  (I read helpful info in the Google Apps section and found an area there to enter DNS information - that feature is moving to the Developer's console.  I entered info there and two places in the Developer's console (under settings in the AppEngine (Customer Domains tab) and under the Networking->CloudDNS  (I also moved domain host to CloudDNS).   I pointed CNAME alias for mail.example.com and mobile.example.com to ghs.googlehosted.com.  Should these point to the IP address ?

Comment: your entries to CNAME mail.example.com and mobile.example.com to ghs.googlehosted.com is ok. however, you need to have A record for ghs.googlexxxx.com. Else,